# Trek Multi-track 750

Tags: tire, trek

I just purchased a Trek multitrack 750 1996 in black. I found it in almost perfect condition and want to upgrade the tires. What is the max tire size you can run on the 750 without any clearance issues?

Comment: Uh, have you considered measuring stuff?

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate of the linked question.  Try reading all the answers and apply them to your bike.  If you still have probs, try asking in [chat]

Comment: I have a 1994 Trek 730, not the same frame but similar, possibly quite similar.  The tightest point on my frame is at the chainstays, especially after I wrapped the drive-side chainstay with a strip of inner tube for chain drops.  I'm running 40mm width tires and they're good but I wouldn't want any larger.  When I picked 40s I tried to leave myself room to add fenders, but it may even be too tight for that, I'll have to see.  You should just find the tightest clearance point on your frame with your current tires and measure the space there and do the math.  (You lucky dog - I wanted a 750.)

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search turned up [a thread at BikeForums](https://www.bikeforums.net/hybrid-bicycles/1122457-what-size-tires-will-mid-90s-trek-multitrack-accept.html) that seems to have a consensus that 40mm is about the max size.  Depending on the particular tire and how inflated it is, a 42mm tire *might* fit.